# UIButton receiving touch events outside bounds when set as leftView of UITextField

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

This has been a bit of a head scratcher for me. In an app I'm building I am using a UITextField, and adding a button as the leftView property. However, it seems that on an iPad (both sim and on device), the button is receiving touches that are well outside its bounds. This is interfering with the ability of the UITextField to become the first responder when the user touches the placeholder text. It seems that when touching the placeholder text, the events are being handled by the button instead of the text field itself. Strangely, this only appears to happen on iPad; it works as expected on the iPhone.

Here is some simple code demonstrating the problem:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {

    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f,
                                                                           10.0f,
                                                                           (self.view.frame.size.width - 20.0f),
                                                                           35.0f)];
    textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
    textField.placeholder = @"Test text";
    [self.view addSubview:textField];

    UIButton *addButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeContactAdd];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpInside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUpOutside) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
    textField.leftView = addButton;
    textField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;    
}

- (void)touchDown:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"touchDown");
}

- (void)touchUpInside {
    NSLog(@"touchUpInside");
}

- (void)touchUpOutside {
     NSLog(@"touchUpOutside");
 }
```

It seems that sometimes touches are still perceived as being inside even though they appear to be outside the button's bounds. Then getting even further right, the button only receives UIControlEventTouchDown then UIControlEventTouchUpOutside.

```
2013-07-25 11:51:44.217 TestApp[22722:c07] touchDown
2013-07-25 11:51:44.306 TestApp[22722:c07] touchUpInside
2013-07-25 11:51:44.689 TestApp[22722:c07] touchDown
2013-07-25 11:51:44.801 TestApp[22722:c07] touchUpOutside
```

**EDIT**
Here is an example with the background color of the button changed as well as the approximate zones that trigger the events above. Also, I checked the frame of the button and it is less than 30px wide.

[image: Example image]

Comment: change the background color of the button and see what it fills up of the text view, from there set the frame accordingly if that does not work, subclass the button and use the point in side method of all uiview classes and see what it says the positions are if they are odd like negative numbers then return NO from that function. This doesn't answer your question but it may help.

Comment: Try using buttonWithType Custom, and set the frame for the button; This way you can control the button's dimensions, whether uibuttontypecontactadd's frame is not well known. There are probabily different frames for this kind of button for iPhone/iPad hence the different behaviour

Comment: Appreciate the suggestions, but I've checked the frame and it doesn't appear to match up. It's only about 30px wide. I've added a screenshot above with the background color of the button changed and the approximate zones that these events are triggered as well. I may end up going the route of subclassing either UIButton or UITextField to try to correct the behavior, but wanted to see if maybe I was totally missing something first. Wonder if this is just a bug with UITextField.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sat down and spent some more time on this last night. I was already subclassing UITextField in my real application, so I ended up overriding `-(id)hitTest:withEvent:` as seen below. This has been working fine so far.

```
- (id)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    if ([[super hitTest:point withEvent:event] isEqual:self.leftView]) {
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.leftView.frame, point)) {
            return self.leftView;
        } else {
            return self;
        }
    }

    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I verified your results. I think it's most likely a bug in `UITextView`. Unfortunately, for some reason if you set `leftView`, events in that area are being sent to the wrong view (on the iPad).

I don't have a simple workaround for you since adjusting the frame of the leftView has no effect. I think it needs to be fixed at a lower level than we have access to. Maybe report the bug to Apple and live with it for now?

You could track the location of the touch and ignore it if it's out of bounds, but it seems like a lot of work for a minor bug?

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the confirmation. I was able to fix the behavior fairly easily by overriding `-(id)hitTest:withEvent:` which I detailed in my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Just met this question too, for some other solution I found is adding a check whether the event point located inside the button.

```
- (void)touchUpInside:(UIButton *)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint location = [[[event allTouches] anyObject] locationInView:sender];

    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(sender.bounds, location)) {
        // Outside of bounds, so ignore:
        return;
    }
    // Inside our bounds, so continue as normal:
}
```